# How to pass C# array into a Q# operation within QuantumSimulator Run() command?

Tags: c#, quantum-computing, q#

I'm making a program which uses an array of integers taken in as a parameter from the C# script in `Driver.cs` but it gives the following error:

`Error CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'long[]' to 'Microsoft.Quantum.Simulation.Core.IQArray<long>'`

I have tried to instead pass in an array of strings and convert them inside the program, but an identical error appears:

`Error CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string[]' to 'Microsoft.Quantum.Simulation.Core.IQArray<string>'`

Here is the C# code in `Driver.cs` - `keyArray` is the array that I'm trying to pass to Q#.

```cs
using (var qsim = new QuantumSimulator())
{
    var result = QMain.Run(qsim, keyArray).Result;
    var (res0, res1, res2) = result;
    System.Console.WriteLine(res0 + ", " + res1 + ", " + res2);
}
```

Q# QMain operation in `Operations.qs`:

```
operation QMain(keyCode : Int[]) : (Result, Result, Result)
```

In Q#, `Int` datatype corresponds to C# `long`.

Passing an array of strings failed as well, with the following signature of `QMain`:

```
operation QMain(s : String[]) : (Result, Result, Result)
```

All that I'm getting is the same error whenever I try to use any array as a parameter in `QMain`.

Comment: There's also [quantumcomputing.se] if you're interested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The data type used for passing fixed-length arrays to and from Q# code is `QArray`. You have to create an instance of this data type from your array explicitly before passing it to `QMain`:

```
var result = QMain.Run(qsim, new QArray<long>(keyArray)).Result;
```

You can see an example of passing arrays to Q# [in the samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/Quantum/blob/331886049e00b113a133330515d5a12ade0629c5/Samples/src/SimpleAlgorithms/Driver.cs#L90).

Comment: Thank you so much, wasn't expecting such a fast response :))

Comment: Well, the compiler is telling you exactly what’s wrong! All you had to do is figure out what it wanted you to cast.